# Execute Macro into Visual Basic 2008

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2008, ms-word

I created this Microsoft Word 2010 Macros:

```
Sub Crea_DAF()        
    Selection.WholeStory()
    Selection.Copy()
    ChangeFileOpenDirectory("C:\Users\f.irrera\Desktop\")
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(FileName:="Fascicolo.daf", FileFormat:= _
    wdFormatText, LockComments:=False, Password:="", AddToRecentFiles:=True, _
    WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, _
    SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:= _
    False, Encoding:=1252, InsertLineBreaks:=False, AllowSubstitutions:=False _
    , LineEnding:=wdCRLF, CompatibilityMode:=0)
End Sub
```

I would execute this macros at Event (using Visual Basic 2008 Express Edition):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handl
```

Is it possible?

I am Tryng with:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim var As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
    var.Selection.WholeStory()  <--- Error
    var.Selection.Copy()
    var.ChangeFileOpenDirectory("C:\Users\f.irrera\Desktop\")
    var.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(FileName:="Fascicolo.daf")
End Sub
```

This is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This run:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim var As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application()
    Dim ciao As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document
    ciao.Activate()


    var.Documents.Open(FileName:="C:\Users\f.irrera\Desktop\Fascicolo.doc")
    var.Selection.WholeStory()
    var.Selection.Copy()

    var.ChangeFileOpenDirectory("C:\Users\f.irrera\Desktop\")
    var.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(FileName:="Fascicolo.daf", LockComments:=False, Password:="", WritePassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, EmbedTrueTypeFonts:=False, SaveNativePictureFormat:=False, SaveFormsData:=False, SaveAsAOCELetter:=False, Encoding:=1252, InsertLineBreaks:=False, AllowSubstitutions:=False, CompatibilityMode:=0)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you will be able to access all those properties via the object model.  You can see here (or search on duckduckgo for word/vb.net programming):

http://www.windowsdevcenter.com/pub/a/windows/2006/04/18/programming-word-from-net.html

Alternatively, add that code into the load on word and then just "shell" open the document to with the macro options:

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\OFFICE11\WinWord.exe" "c:\the.doc"
 /mDoStuffMacro

OR

via VBS:

Run_Excel_Macro.vbs "C:\Full\Path\To\Your_Excel_Workbook.xls"

Comment: No problem.  If the answer has solved your problem, then don't forget to mark it as "answered"